# How to solve errors in MySql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, clause

I'm learning Mysql, a newbie.
First I wrote:

```
Select name, count(*)
From Emp
Group By name;
```

and the code was successful.
After that, I added to the code it became:

```
Select *
From Emp
Where (Select name, count(*)
From Emp
Group By name) > 1;
```

and I get an error message too many values.
How to fix that?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name which have the count >1 use having count clause.

Try:

```
Select name, 
       count(*)
From Emp
Group By name
having count(name) > 1;
```

Learn more on: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/

```
select e.*
from Emp e 
INNER JOIN (Select name, 
                   count(*)
            From Emp
            Group By name
            having count(name) > 1
           ) as e2 on e2.name=e.name
```

Comment: thanks, how can sql display all columns (not only column names) that have more than one name

Answer (score 0):

To get all the information of the employees that have the same name, you can do folowing

```
Select e1.*
From Emp  e1 INNER JOIN (Select name
From Emp
Group By name
having count(name) > 1) e2 ON e2.name = e1,name
```

Comment: No need for that `DISTINCT`, it just makes people onfocused.